# Extracting Capture Group from Non-Capture Group in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string, let's call it `output`, that's equals the following:

```
ltm data-group internal str_testclass { 
    records { 
        baz { 
            data "value 1" 
        } 
        foobar { 
            data "value 2" 
        }
        topaz {}
    } 
    type string 
}
```

And I'm trying to extract the substring between the quotes for a given **"record"** name.  So given `foobar` I want to extract `value 2`.  The substring I want to extract will always come in the form I have prescribed above, after the "record" name, a whitespace, an open bracket, a new line, whitespace, the string `data`, and then the substring I want to capture is between the quotes from there.  The one exception is when there is no value, which will always happen like I have prescribed above with `topaz`, in which case after the "record" name there will just be an open and closed bracket and I'd just like to get an empty string for this.  How could I write a line of Java to capture this?  So far I have ......

```
String myValue = output.replaceAll("(?:foobar\\s{\n\\s*data "([^\"]*)|()})","$1 $2");
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You say you want to "extract", but you present code that appears intended to *substitute*.  Which is it you really want?

Comment: It doesn't really matter to me whether replaceAll is used or something else, as long as it accomplishes the task at hand.  I just thought replaceAll could be used to create a nice, simple one liner.

Comment: This isn't java compilable code. You must escape the `"` sign: `\"`. I also guess that you meant `\n` instead of `\\n`.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I threw together my progress so far a bit too quickly.  It may have some syntax errors.  I corrected it as best I could.

Comment: @user2150250, the question is what *is* the task at hand?  I take your response to indicate that you only want to obtain the value, but that's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex shouldn't even compile, because you are not escaping the `"` inside your regex String, so it is ending your String at the first `"` inside your regex.

Instead, try this regex:

```
String regex = key + "\\s\\{\\s*\\n\\s*data\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"";
```

You can check out how it works [here on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tG0iT7/1).

Try something like this `getRecord()` method where key is the record 'name' you're searching for, e.g. foobar, and the input is the string you want to search through.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "ltm data-group internal str_testclass { \n" +
            "    records { \n" +
            "        baz { \n" +
            "            data \"value 1\" \n" +
            "        } \n" +
            "        foobar { \n" +
            "            data \"value 2\" \n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "        topaz {}\n" +
            "    } \n" +
            "    type string \n" +
            "}";

    String bazValue = getRecord("baz", input);
    String foobarValue = getRecord("foobar", input);
    String topazValue = getRecord("topaz", input);

    System.out.println("Record data value for 'baz' is '" + bazValue + "'");
    System.out.println("Record data value for 'foobar' is '" + foobarValue + "'");
    System.out.println("Record data value for 'topaz' is '" + topazValue + "'");
}

private static String getRecord(String key, String input) {
    String regex = key + "\\s\\{\\s*\\n\\s*data\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        //if we find a record with data return it
        return matcher.group(1);
    } else {
        //else see if the key exists with empty {}
        final Pattern keyPattern = Pattern.compile(key);
        Matcher keyMatcher = keyPattern.matcher(input);
        if (keyMatcher.find()) {
            //return empty string if key exists with empty {}
            return "";
        } else {
            //else handle error, throw exception, etc.
            System.err.println("Record not found for key: " + key);
            throw new RuntimeException("Record not found for key: " + key);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Record data value for 'baz' is 'value 1'
>     Record data value for 'foobar' is 'value 2'
>     Record data value for 'topaz' is ''

Answer (score 2):

Let's start extracting "records" structure with following regex `ltm\s+data-group\s+internal\s+str_testclass\s*\{\s*records\s*\{\s*(?<records>([^\s}]+\s*\{\s*(data\s*"[^"]*")?\s*\}\s*)*)\}\s*type\s*string\s*\}`

Then from "records" group, just [find](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) for sucessive match against `[^\s}]+\s*\{\s*(?:data\s*"(?<data>[^"]*)")?\s*\}\s*`. The "data" group contains what's you're looking for and will be null in "topaz" case.

Java strings:

- `"ltm\\s+data-group\\s+internal\\s+str_testclass\\s*\\{\\s*records\\s*\\{\\s*(?<records>([^\\s}]+\\s*\\{\\s*(data\\s*\"[^\"]*\")?\\s*\\}\\s*)*)\\}\\s*type\\s*string\\s*\\}"`
- `"[^\\s}]+\\s*\\{\\s*(?:data\\s*\"(?<data>[^\"]*)\")?\\s*\\}\\s*"`

Demo:

```
String input = 
    "ltm data-group internal str_testclass {\n" + 
    "  records {\n" +
    "      baz {\n" + 
    "          data \"value 1\"\n" + 
    "      }\n" +
    "      foobar {\n" + 
    "          data \"value 2\"\n" + 
    "      }\n" +
    "      topaz {}\n" +
    "      empty { data \"\"}\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "    type string\n" + 
    "}";

Pattern language = Pattern.compile("ltm\\s+data-group\\s+internal\\s+str_testclass\\s*\\{\\s*records\\s*\\{\\s*(?<records>([^\\s}]+\\s*\\{\\s*(data\\s*\"[^\"]*\")?\\s*\\}\\s*)*)\\}\\s*type\\s*string\\s*\\}");
Pattern record   = Pattern.compile("(?<name>[^\\s}]+)\\s*\\{\\s*(?:data\\s*\"(?<data>[^\"]*)\")?\\s*\\}\\s*");

Matcher lgMatcher = language.matcher(input);
if (lgMatcher.matches()) {
  String records = lgMatcher.group();
  Matcher rdMatcher = record.matcher(records);
  while (rdMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("%s:%s%n", rdMatcher.group("name"), rdMatcher.group("data"));
  }
} else {
  System.err.println("Language not recognized");
}
```

Output:

```
baz:value 1
foobar:value 2
topaz:null
empty:
```

Alernatives: As your parsing a custom language, you can give a try to write an ANTLR grammar or create Groovy DSL.

Comment: Mind just formatting your answer into some Java?  I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Mind formatting it into some Java with the `find` and all?  Like something that will compile.  I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Also, is it possible to have it return an empty string instead of `null` for `topaz` so I can distinguish between a record that has no value and a record that doesn't exist in the first place?

Comment: @user2150250 what about a record that exists and has data that happens to be the empty string?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Like where you might see `data ""`?  I can guarantee for this question that won't happen.  If that's the case you'll just have the open and closed brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
(?:foobar\s{\s*data "(.*)")
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the replaceAll() isn't necessary here. Would something like this work:

```
String var1 = "foobar";
String regex = '(?:' + var1 + '\s{\n\s*data "([^"]*)")';
```

You can then use this as your regex to pass into your pattern and matcher to find the substring.

You can simple transform this into a function so that you can pass variables into it for your search string:

```
public static void SearchString(String str)
{
    String regex = '(?:' + str + '\s{\n\s*data "([^"]*)")';
}
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the `topaz` use case above though does it?

Comment: This won't even compile. In Java, anything inside of single quotes is interpreted as a character literal. You have to use double quotes for it to be interpreted as a string, then you'll need to escape the double quotes inside of the actual regex.